# Do sessions get loaded after vimrc, and is there a block to specify loading code AFTER a session is loaded?

Tags: sessions

```
    set sessionoptions+=globals 
    if !exists('g:EGbufs')
        if exists('g:EGbufsstring')
            exe "let g:EGbufs=".g:EGbufsstring
        else
            let g:EGbufs = {}
        endif
    endif
```

I have this in my .vimrc.
When I load a session, I can `:echo g:EGbufsstring` for the right result.

But for some reason, my second exists conditional fails, and so `g:EGbufs` is set to a empty dictionary. There might be another bug, but I've used echo and echoerr around this code to check the value of the string and it tells me the variable doesn't exist.

Does a vimsession get loaded AFTER the .vimrc? The only work around I can think of is writing to a file the string I want to load, and reading it in the vimrc. I'm already trying to work around lack of support for saving dictionaries in a session. I guess my other option is to run this load conditional in the function that I need it, but that's just a little ugly.

UPDATE:

Ah, I thought I had it with `autocmd SessionLoadPost call LoadBufsString()` but I can't seem to make it work. Thought it might be because it only triggers on manual `:mks` but that is not the case either. Probably I just need to sort out the syntax.

Comment: Try removing doubled `s` in `EGbufSString` - or you have a typo in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer. autocommand with the

`|SessionLoadPost|  after loading a session file`

event. It hit me when I realised I want something to trigger this code.

`autocmd SessionLoadPost * call LoadBufsString()`

does it. I needed to specify * for the filematcher, for some reason. Not sure if that is mandatory for all autocommands.

Comment: You can use the parameter to filter specific session filepaths (e.g. `autocmd SessionLoadPost myproject/*.session ...`). All autocommands take a parameter like that.